# Object undefined in Meteor / JavaScript

Tags: javascript, meteor

I am building an app in Meteor. I am trying to pass a user object into a template, but the console keeps printing out "user undefined" although I clearly define the user object in my controller:

controller.js:

```
checkoutController = RouteController.extend({
waitOn: function () { 
    var sessionId = Session.get('sessionId');
    Meteor.subscribe('cartItems', sessionId);
    Meteor.subscribe('userProfileExtended2');
},
data: function(){
    return {
        user: Meteor.users.findOne(this.params._id) //user defined
    };
},
action: function() {
    this.render('Checkout');
    console.log('user:')
    console.log('user: ' + user);
}
});
```

My publish.js, which publishes the user object:

```
//this is for a user to edit his/her own profile since there's no admin check

Meteor.publish('userProfileExtended2', function(userId) {
if(!this.userId) return null;
var currUser = Meteor.users.find(this.userId);

//need to add logic to make sure user can only edit his/her account
console.log('user searched for from userprofileextended2 is ' + this.userId);
return Meteor.users.find(this.userId);
});
```

Here is my route:

```
Router.route('/checkout', {name: 'Checkout', controller: 'checkoutController'});
```

Notes:

1) My terminal console prints out the user Id correctly
2) My browser console prints out "ReferenceError: user is not defined"

Any thoughts? Thank you in advance!

Comment: change the data from the object context to this `data:function(){ user = Meteor.users.findOne(this.params._id)}`

Comment: Thanks - I'm still running into that issue though :/

Comment: hi -  console.log('user: ' + user); is already after the this.render('Checkout');

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a couple of issues in your code which can cause confusion, namely you are returning the wrong user in the subscription function. The second is you need to specify which user you want to see:

```
Meteor.publish('userProfileExtended2', function() {
    return Meteor.users.find({_id: this.userId});
});
```

You also need to print the correct variable when you render the page:

```
console.log('user: ' + Meteor.user())
```

You don't need to use search for the user. You can use `Meteor.user()` in code or `{{currentUser}}` in your templates.

Also when you send down the user's document using `Meteor.users.find` be careful to use projections so that only the fields you intend to share are provided and not the entire document. This can enhance the security of the user's document being viewed.

Comment: hi - thank you for your answer. however, i tried it and i am still getting the same error.. is there any other information i can give you to help me?

Comment: @user1547174 Thank you for your clarification/edit. I have updated the answer you can use `Meteor.user()` nothing more is needed.